# Topology consisting of symmetric intervals: Compact subsets

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{T}=\{(-a,a)\,|\,a>0\}\,\cup\,\{\emptyset\}$ be a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Under which conditions is a subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ compact wrt the topology $\mathcal{T}$? My claim is: 
*$A$ has a minimum and maximum $\implies$ $A$ is compact.* 
*Proof*: Set $m:=\text{min}A$ and $M:=\text{max}A$. Choose $\mathcal{U}=\{U_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ to be a cover of $A$ by open sets $U_{i}$, that means $A\subset\bigcup_{i\in I}U_{i}$, whereas $U_{i} = (-x_{i},x_{i})$ for all $i\in I$.
Now, since $m, M\in A$ by definition, we can write $A = [m,M]\cap A\subset \bigcup_{i\in I}U_{i}$. This means that there exist $i_{0}, i_{1}\in I$ such that $m\in (-x_{i_{0}}, x_{i_{0}})$ and $M\in (-x_{i_{1}}, x_{i_{1}})$, so $m < x_{i_{0}}$ and $M < x_{i_{1}}$. Therefore, $\{(-x_{i_{0}}, x_{i_{0}}), (-x_{i_{1}}, x_{i_{1}})\}$ is our finite subcover (more precise: the subcover $\{(-\text{max}(x_{i_{0}},x_{i_{1}}),\text{max}(x_{i_{0}},x_{i_{1}}))\}$ also does the job).$\quad\square$
Is this proof/claim correct? And if so, then "$\Longleftarrow$" is also true, right?
I think boundedness and the existence of only the minimum OR the maximum is not sufficient, since for $A = [-1,2)$ the cover by $\{(-2+\frac{1}{n}, 2-\frac{1}{n})\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has obviously no finite subcover.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You do need more than the minimum or maximum, but you don't always need both. For example, $(-1, 2]$ *is* compact, since some $(x_i, x_i)$ must contain $2$, and thus all of $(-1, 2]$. You seem to be close to a necessary and sufficient condition. Have another try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break it down to smaller pieces:

> **Lemma 1.** $A$ is compact if and only if $A\cup -A$ is.

*Proof.* "$\Rightarrow$" follows from the fact that $x\mapsto -x$ is a homeomorphism and (finite) union of compact subspaces is compact.

"$\Leftarrow$" follows from the fact that a covering of $A$ is automatically a covering of $A\cup -A$ by symmetry of our open subsets. $\Box$

> **Lemma 2.** Let $A$ be a symmetric subset, i.e. $A=A\cup -A$. Then $A$ is compact if and only if $A$ contains $\sup(A)$.

*Proof.* "$\Rightarrow$" If $\sup(A)$ is not in $A$, then define $x_n=\sup(A)-\frac{1}{n}$ or $x_n=n$ if $\sup(A)=\infty$. Either way $(-x_n,x_n)$ covers $A$ and it has no finite subcover, which I leave as an exercise.

"$\Leftarrow$" Note that if $\sup(A)\in (-a,a)$ for some $a>0$, then $A\subseteq (-a,a)$. In other words an open covering of $A$ has to contain an interval fully covering entire $A$. Thus $A$ is compact. $A$ being symmetric is crucial here: if $a>\sup(A)$, then $-a<\inf(A)$ because $\inf(A)=-\sup(A)$. $\Box$

> **Lemma 3.** $\sup(A\cup -A)=\max\big(|\inf(A)|, |\sup(A)|\big)$

which I also leave as an exercise.

All in all we get:

> **Conclusion.** A subset $A$ is compact if and only if $A$ contains $\max\big(|\inf(A)|, |\sup(A)|\big)$.

Comment: Nice, thank you.